# setup 2 domains in my docker-compose + nginx-proxy

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to configure 2 domains to run on the same VPS.

using nginx-proxy + letsencrypt + docker-compose

- i have setup both my domains to point to my VPS
- i want to run 2 different sites with blazor client-side. (as a start simple index.html is fine)

how will i move on from here?

my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '2'

services:

  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - "default"
      - "proxy-tier"

  proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: letsencrypt
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
      - "proxy"
    depends_on:
      - "proxy"
    networks:
      - "default"
      - "proxy-tier"

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=docker.DOMAIN.dk
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=docker.DOMAIN.dk
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=EMAIL@hotmail.com
    volumes:
      - ./portainer/:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"


volumes:
  certs:
  vhost.d:
  html:

networks:
  proxy-tier:
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing to use it with an other software like Traffik?
Using traffik to proxy your traffic and handle your certificates of let's-encrypt. So you have one container who does it both and you can fire up as many docker container with traffik labels to route with tls certificate to new subdomains etc.

Full Smarthome Example:
https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-2-docker-tutorial/#3_Domain_Name

Traffik handle multiple domains: https://plexguide.com/threads/howto-configure-traefik-to-handle-multiple-domain-names.3420/

Or the traffik doc: https://docs.traefik.io/v2.2/routing/routers/#tls

Comment: I will take a look at it, to see if it makes sense to change it around. Thanks for the links.